# What happens to privileges if the requirements change?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

On Stack Overflow the current [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) thresholds are considerably higher than a newly created site such as [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) which tells me that popularity dictates privilege thresholds.

So what happens if I attained privileges and then the threshold is increased?

---

[image]

---

If this answer already exists elsewhere then please let me know.

Comment: This is actually covered in the linked posts. :) Privileges, unlike badges, are absolutely tied to rep. If your rep changes or the privilege levels change, you lose the privilege if you no longer have the required reputation.

Comment: @Catija Thank you for that. I was not aware that this is a beta vs. graduated site specific threshold; TIL what is a "graduated" site. I think my search skills failed me because I was not familiar with terminology. On a tangent, how does a site graduate?

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) should give you a general idea for the process.

Comment: @Catija thanks, were there ever suggestions/discussions to continue raising the threshold as a graduated site gains popularity?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: Yes, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261525/can-we-make-automatically-scaling-reputation-thresholds-work?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you'll lose them. If the site is large enough to graduate (and get a custom design), it's certainly large enough to gather enough reputation for the increased privilege levels.