# Are graduating sites considered launched?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-declined, area-51, graduating-sites

When designing community ads, I've generally gone to look at the [Area 51 Launched Page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched) to see where I could put ads (and frown when the best sites were still in beta). I've usually expected that all sites would be there.

I'm going to be taking [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) as an example:

Code Review is a site that has apparently "graduated" through the design-independent process. As seen in their [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september), they've graduated, under the conditions of [this design-independent graduation post on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation). They should also be in the footer, but apparently [they aren't, due to something wickety wackety thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september):

> After digging, it's clear we can't simply shove new links into the already crowded space, and a different solution is needed all together. We will be discussing the site footer in the coming days so we can determine how to tackle this at its root.

Looking for the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

I would expect these new graduated sites to be showing up under the Area 51 Launched page. There isn't really a definition of "launched": I would expect it to just hold graduated sites. Of course, if it's like the footer, then it might not happen in a while...

With design-independent graduated sites still holding the same logo/favicon, it's hard now to distinguish between graduated and beta sites. Are design-independent sites showing up under the Area 51 launched page?

---

Now the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)!

Of course, if that's going to take a while (which I likely expect it will), can we have a separate resource on Meta SE - a list of graduated sites? I have a hunch that this will likely be [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), but I think that this will be extremely helpful (if you want, I can think of an ultimate creative way to list sites and make it awesome!).

---

Any words?

Comment: Actually Code Review may be a bad ecample of what you want to show, since it has officially been scheduled for graduation since almost a year ago: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2545/37660

Comment: Re: feature-request, y'all can start any post you want and community-maintain it. ;)

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow Aya, but I assume that they have technically graduated using the design-independent process?

Comment: Fully Correct:]

Comment: As of a bit earlier today, sites that graduate without a design will also show up on A51 as launched.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thank you for the bug report. When it comes to your [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) it's hard to see how anything we might build would be more effective than a community-maintained meta post right now. We just launched this new process, and reports like yours about bits and pieces which are knocked out of place are rolling in. That means we should be addressing the bugs, rather than devoting time to building things which work around and thereby prolong the bugs.

So yes, I am going to [status-decline](/questions/tagged/status-decline) this request, but a meta post which fulfills the same purpose is great way to go.

Comment: Alright! Sounds good to me :) I'll get started on a neat, creative meta post right now :D