# Are Pro Tempore Moderators going to quit working when the beta has finished?

Tags: support, moderators

I looked at users who earned the [Constable](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/badges/99/constable) badge. Excluding a few, they are not moderator. When the Beta is finished, are Pro Tempore Moderators going to quit working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends on the result of the election, which is always held as part of the [graduation procedure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation). For example, on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/1), *pro-tempore* moderators [J.R.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/badges/94/constable?userid=113) and [WendiKidd](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/badges/94/constable?userid=289) participated in the election, and were chosen. Had they decided not to run, or if they weren't chosen, they would have stopped being a ♦ moderator.

Comment: Both JR and Wendi were ELL pro-tems. And there's no & in ELL. You're thinking of ELU.

Comment: @Catija you're right - this was just one example.