# How to determine if a beta site is ready to support a post-graduation election?

Tags: discussion, election, graduating-sites

After a site graduates, we proceed to [have moderator elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260754/351283).  The graduation of [Mechanics.SE](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) was delayed for around 9 months because it was unable to "support an election":

> But I don't think this site can support an election just yet. In the past we've noticed two problems with sites that don't have a large middle class:
>
> 1. 3 or fewer viable candidates nominate themselves.
> 2. Low voter turnout.
>
> So we are delaying the graduation of Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair until there are more potential moderator candidates and voters. -- [Jon Ericson ♦](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1447), December 30, 2015

So I think: *Ah ha! We better work on preparing Islam.SE for a post-graduation election*.  ([Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14922/islam) lists us as just breaching the [10 questions per day mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/351283).)  Only, it's not clear to me what precisely the goal is here.

**Question**: How to determine if a beta site is ready to support a post-graduation election?

I'm expecting the answer would be some kind of desirable "number of users with >X reputation" distribution.

---

I found a few scattered comments about this:

> We already look at "can the site sustain an election?" and "can community moderation work effectively after privilege levels increase?" as graduation criteria. -- [Pops ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation#comment850181_260762), 2015
>
> The only thing holding CR back from graduating is the lack of high rep users - there just aren't enough 1k+, 3k+ users on the site, and it can't quite yet sustain an election. -- [Tim Post ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291955/can-we-add-code-review-to-the-migration-list#comment184710_291956), 2013

Comment: Since I'm now a moderator on Mechanics, I feel almost obligated to write an answer for you, which won't give you specifics (as I don't have them ... someone does, obviously), but to show you things on Islam.SE which would definitely help you get graduated. They surely helped us. It's a great feeling graduating. Hopefully you'll see the fruits of your labors pay off soon.