# How does the new beta/graduation philosophy apply to spinoff sites?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase, beta-sites

[The recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) formally acknowledging long beta periods seem like a huge improvement: our longstanding small but awesome beta sites can breathe easier.

I'm wondering about one specific case: betas that are spinoffs of larger sites, sometimes fully graduated sites. The two examples I'm personally most familiar with are [Coffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/) as a subtopic of [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), and [Poker](https://poker.stackexchange.com/) as a subtopic of [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/).

So per the announcement, all betas including those sites are in no risk of being shut down. Is that based on applying the same general criteria: helpful content, no moderation issues, no time limit? Or given that shutting down a subtopic beta is slightly less drastic (it could be folded into another site), and [there's already a higher bar for creation of those sites](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17846/23227), do the criteria change in any way?

Similarly, when new spinoff sites are proposed, should they be expecting that if they make it to beta, they'll be able to exist indefinitely no matter the activity level, or should they be expecting to have to meet a higher bar after launch as well?

(I'm definitely not trying to suggest that anything needs to be done, I just want to understand the CMs' thinking about cases like this.)