# Minimal allowed activity on a beta site

Tags: support, area-51, beta-phase, beta-sites

Some time ago too low activity on a beta-stage site was valid reason for closing it ([example](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51461/mind), closed on 8-th day of beta in April 2014).

In June 2015 Ana released [new rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/252301), which say that small sites are now ok. Now spam, non-clearing moderator flags and failing to "Be Nice" are said to be more probable reasons for closing a beta site. (Still high activity is needed to graduate.)

Does this mean that now there is no danger for a beta site to be closed due to too-low-activity at all (at least, during the first 90 days)? Or do there still exist some minimal activity restrictions for a beta site (either strictly formalized or subjective)? And what about minimal activity requirements after 90 days have elapsed?

Comment: 90 days does not matter. Passing from private to open beta does. Low activity in private beta is _still_ a reason to close a site. Most recently, Sitecore was [just about to be closed](http://meta.sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/41) but the decision was reversed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the "new rules" post you linked, emphasis mine:

> If a **public beta site** does not produce consistently helpful content, and lacks the caretakers needed for flags and spam to get handled and our Be Nice policy to be upheld, it will be closed.

I don't think any public beta sites have been closed since <s>about 2013</s> 2015 (thanks for the correction, animuson♦).  *Private* beta sites, on the other hand, sometimes fail to make it into public beta.

Area 51 is an imperfect predictor of site viability.  Sometimes a site sounds great in *principle*, but then people actually try to make it work and find that it's really hard to form good questions and answers, or it turned out there were only about 42 useful questions in the field, or probably other things.  If the people dedicated enough to the site to work on it through Area 51 and join a private beta can't make it work, the presumption is that there's something in the concept that needs to be reworked.  So, rather than launching a public beta that's very likely to fail, SE sends it back to the drawing board -- they close the site and invite the users to start a new proposal on Area 51, with changes based on what they learned from the experience.  There are sites that failed on the first try but succeeded on the second.

Comment: Well, [Arabic](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62022/arabic-language) happened in 2015, although some of us would agree that probably shouldn't have made it out of private beta to begin with, so that's a fairly poor example.

Comment: So, then: are there some (formal or informal) requirements related to activity in private beta? I mean: something more concrete than just "*X* (administrator) decided that activity is too low".

Comment: @animuson oh, thanks -- missed (or forgot about) that one.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, so then: What are requirements/recommendations related to levels of activity in *private* beta? Or is this purely opinion-based? Or should I ask a separate question for that?

Comment: @Sasha you should probably ask a separate question about that, being explicit that it's about private beta.  Only community managers will be able to answer definitively (I see nothing in the A51 FAQ about this), though maybe people who've been part of failed private betas will be able to contribute info.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, what do you mean by "SE sends it back to the drawing board", please?

Comment: @Bebs back to Area 51; people can start a new proposal based on what they learned, and this has actually worked (not just theoretical).  See my edit.