# Do mature Stack Exchange sites ever close?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, closed-sites

Communities need to pass some critical mass and quality criteria in order to come out of Area51 into StackExchange proper, and be "born". But do sites ever "die" ?

Put another way - is the number of StackExchange sites over time strictly a monotonically increasing function ?

A simple "yes/no" answer would be fantastic, but if this generates discussion, I'm all the happier.

Note : I'm explicitly referring to sites that have **already** exited Area51 and public beta.

[Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) does not seem to answer my question.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the original question. I hadn't found it in the initial search. It seems to imply the sites _can_ be closed, which is the answer I was looking for.