# What happens to a Stack Exchange site if it has almost no traffic?

Tags: discussion, activity, traffic

While scrolling through [the sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#users) of Stack Exchange, I found that some sites don't even get a question a day. For example, [Beer, Wine & Spirits](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/), [Veganism & Vegetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/) and [Ebooks](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/). Some sites even have fewer than 50 visits per day.

What happens to those sites? Will they be closed as a result, or will Stack Exchange do anything to try and "save them"?

Comment: They will be viewed by a smaller audience? I'm not sure what you're asking. Note that some sites are in [beta phase](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta). See [Area 51 - FAQ](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: I dont understand the downvotes. This is a valid question, and attracted a factual answer.

Comment: @GhostCat votes on Meta are very rarely given based on whether the question is valid or not. It's all about what people feel about what's being discussed. I'll take a guess and assume downvotes here are due to the question being trivial, or not clear to some people.

Comment: There's no need to add Stack Exchange on every site, I have never heard anyone call EL&U "English Language & Usage Stack Exchange", every site belongs to its "mother".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a community around a topic of a site is no longer actively maintaining or building the body of knowledge each SE site wants to be, then a site will be closed and archived.

From [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites)

> If a public beta site does not produce consistently helpful content, and lacks the caretakers needed for flags and spam to get handled and our Be Nice policy to be upheld, it will be closed.

Before that decision is made a community manager will probably reach out on site meta and see if there is anything they can do to revive the sites topic. Tweaking the site scope can be considered. Or a rename.

If the options have run out then the site will close. This happened before ([twice on the same topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257720/158100)) and will happen in the future. The questions and answers are preserved in a datadump.

Comment: I can see the company doing anything with a small site these days unless the site gives them problems, eg someone on twitter does not like it.  It takes staff time to close down a site.

Comment: @IanRingrose yeah, it will not be the highest, if any priority. They are certainly not actively looking for sites to close.